# Moving the background image of iPhone upon event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, animation, background

I have a navigation based app where a certain pushed view has a nice background image. Now this view contains a UITextView which is transparent so my background shows all over the whole view except the top which holds the navigation bar. Now when I start editing the textview I would like the for the textview and the background image to "slide" up a few pixles under the navigation bar to be more visible when the keyboard shows up (without keyboard it is centered in on the screen).

I set the background with:

```
UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = background;
[background release];
```

But this does not allow me to move it. So I guess I have to make a subview or something to get this to work. I already have the animation for the textview in place, it's just the background image I also would like to move. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `UIImageView` for the background...